# Insert images into the menu list

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to populate my menu items with an image/logo on each of the third menu list, please see example below.

[image]

I've been using Silverstripe to populate the menu items, below is my code so far without the images. Can someone please point me to the right direction on how I go about inserting the images/logos on the third level menu?

```
  // initialise plugins
  jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
  });

  </script>

  <ul class="sf-menu">
  <% control Menu(1) %>
     <li>
        <a href="#a">$MenuTitle</a>
         <% if Children %>
           <ul><% control Children %>
              <li>
                 <a href="#aa">$MenuTitle</a>

                  <% if Children %>
           <ul><% control Children %>
              <li>
                 <a href="#aa">$MenuTitle</a>
              </li>
              <% end_control %>

              </ul><% end_if %>
              </li>
              <% end_control %>

              </ul><% end_if %>

     <!--<li>
        <a href="#">menu item</a>
     </li>-->

        </li> <!--current-->
  <% end_control %><!--   <li>
        <a href="#">menu item</a>
     </li>   -->
  </ul> <!--sf-menu-->
```

Thanks heaps.
S:)

**UPDATE** below is my Page.php, and I have insert $Image.SetSize(20,20) $MenuTitle to my third level menu. However everytime i tried to insert an image through CMS, there is error coming up in CMS. Sorry i'm new to this, any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
class Page extends SiteTree {

public static $db = array(
);

public static $has_one = array(
        'MenuImage' => 'Image'
);

function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Images", new ImageField('MenuImage','Menu image'));

    return $fields;
}
}
     class Page_Controller extends ContentController {


public static $allowed_actions = array (
);

public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // Note: you should use SS template require tags inside your templates 
    // instead of putting Requirements calls here.  However these are 
    // included so that our older themes still work
    Requirements::themedCSS('layout'); 
    Requirements::themedCSS('typography'); 
    Requirements::themedCSS('form'); 
}
}
```

here is the error info.

[User Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT * FROM "Page" WHERE "ID" = 15 Table 'ss_show.page' doesn't exist
POST /Show/admin/EditForm/field/MenuImage/EditFileForm

Line 525 in C:\wamp\www\Show\sapphire\core\model\MySQLDatabase.php

Comment: how you can able get image in menu please help me i m tring to same menu structure....

Comment: Hi Anudeep, I asked this question 2.5 years ago, sorry I can't remember exactly how I did it at the time. However please read my update above if you are using Silverstripe (and I think that's how I did it), it may give you some directions. I suggest you to open a new question to pin point your problem, someone may be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with soneone's help. Just in case others are in the same situation, it is because I didn't rebuild my database. Visit mysite.com/dev/build to rebuild the database. The code above in the update works after that. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  Make sure to accept your answer so that others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an image on your page object, you can render it in your template by doing something like this:

$MyImage.SetWidth(50) $MenuTitle

"$MyImage.SetWidth(50)" will output an image tag with an image resized to 50px wide. See the [SilverStripe image reference](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/image#resizing-in-templates) for more info.

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks very much for the hint. I have managed to insert an image tab in Silverstripe, but everytime I tried to upload an image the error above shows up in CMS. I have attached my Page.php under update above. I'm new to this, so any of your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have the menu image yet, follow the official documentation to do so: http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks for the link. I've been following the tutorial this morning, and I've got an error everytime I update an image in CMS. Please see the update, would you be able to help me out? Thanks.